# Find $\delta$ to achieve $|4x-8| < \epsilon$ when $|x-2| < \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

The Problem:

Find a number $\delta$ such that if $|x-2| < \delta,$  then  $|4x-8| <   \epsilon$  where $\epsilon$$ = 1/10$

How I'd normally work it out:
$$ \epsilon >|4x-8|  $$
$$ \epsilon >4|x-2|  $$
$$ \epsilon/4 >|x-2|  $$

Let's take $\delta = \epsilon / 4$ and then go on to prove it.

Now my question is **where does the $\epsilon=1/10$ part come in?**

Comment: you solved it in the case where $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, so for a fixed $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{10}$ you would just apply the relationship between delta and epsilon to find the particular delta.

Comment: How would you go about doing that? $\delta = 1/40$?

Comment: $\delta = 1/40$ (or any smaller $\delta$) is correct. Think of your equation $\delta = \epsilon/4$ as defining $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$. You then evaluate the function at $\epsilon = 1/10$.

Comment: Right: $\delta = \frac 1 {40}$. If $2 - \frac 1 {40} < x <  2 + \frac 1 {40} $ then  $8 - \frac 1 {10} < 4x < 8 + \frac 1 {10} $.

Answer (score 1):

think about what the epsilon-delta proof is telling you, for every $\epsilon>|4x-8|$ you can find $\delta>|x-2|.$ now the $\frac{1}{10}$ is just an example of a value that you need to use the relationship you proved to get $\delta$, there is nothing special. it is just like when you first start to learn about functions sometimes you got question like "what is the value of $f(2)$ where $f(x)=x^2$"(ofc this example probably didn't happened to you but the general idea behind those 2 is the same, to understand what the relationship you showed means)